# Trying to understand joint probability distribution density

Tags: joint-distribution, density-estimation

I have a bag with 100000 coins of different size, weight, color and shape.

I remove all the coins from the bag. I take each coin, toss it in the air and note how it fell - heads or tails. I have a very limited amount of paper, so I write down some notes about the toss and then put the coin back in the bag.

When all coins are back in the bag, I take a random coin out of the bag.

I look at the features of the coin and then toss it. What's the probability of heads given the coin features?

**What statistics do I need to collect to make the optimal prediction and how to make the prediction based on those statistics?**

I got this question when I tried to get the priors for data having hierarchical partitioning where each deeper node has objects that are closer, but the number of those objects is fewer.

Comment: Your description is awfully vague: exactly what do you record when you "write down some notes"?

Comment: >"exactly what do you record when you "write down some notes"?" I have a goal, stated in the question - to make a prediction based on object properties. Figuring what to write down is 90% of the answer. What statistics do I need to collect for prediction and how to make the prediction based on those statistics?

Comment: I have voted to re-open your question, but I should let you know that I had to override votes from several thoughtful community members who felt it was still not sufficiently clear.  If you can then, please continue to clarify and focus your question.